# Finding the 100th 200th and so on records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have big table in SQL Server like this:

**tbl_point**:

```
point     time
1         dec 12 12 pm
2         dec 12 12 01 pm
.
. 
100       dec 15 2 pm
. 
.
200       dec 18 5 pm
```

I need to select the 100th, 200th, 300th to n00th record

Like

```
100     dec 15 2 pm
200     dec 18 5 pm
.
.
```

Comment: Just to be clear,we are talking about rows with a point value of 100, 200 etc, not "row" 100, 200, depending on what order they are selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from tbl_point where point%100=0 and point>0
```